# What's the best way to automatically generate a .env-sample file from a .env file using Python or shell commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I've been using python-decouple to read my .env file, and it has been working great. To ensure that sensitive information is not pushed to GitHub, I've been manually creating a .env-sample file with just the variable names and pushing that to the repository instead.

However, I sometimes forget to update the .env-sample file when I make changes to the .env file. It's a manual task that can be quite error-prone.

I was wondering if there is an automatic way to generate the .env-sample file using Python or any other shell commands. It would be super helpful if there's a more efficient and reliable approach to keeping my sample file up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is make a Python file (we'll call it `deploy.py`)

`deploy.py`

```
env_list= []

with open("folder/.env", "r") as fh_env:
    for env_line in fh_env:
        env_list.append(env_line.replace('\n', ''))

with open("folder/.env-sample", "a") as fh_env_example:
    for variable in env_list:
        var_only = variable.split("=")[0] 
        fh_env_example.write(f"{var_only}=XXXXX\n")
```

This will fil the env-example file with variables only and put the key down as 'XXXXX'

After this, you can execute a powershell command that calls `deploy.py` to execute the code.

This can obviously be customized to your own needs, but it serves as an example on how you *might* do it.